# SSRS html expression ordered list start attribute not working

Tags: html, reporting-services, tags, html-lists

I inserted a textbox in my SSRS rdl file, and I added an HTML placeholder to add the following HTML code.

=<ol type=""1"" start=""7"">

Content here;

I would like to start the counting from 7 onwards. The code above does not work.

Output:

7. Details here.
8. Details here.
9. Details here.

How am I going to achieve the output. Thanks for your help. ^_^

Comment: Your syntax should give an error. It's expecting something like `="<ol type='1' start='7'>" & Fields!Details.Value & "</ol>`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/importing-html-into-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I am using Reporting Service version 13.0.4259.0. Is it supported? Thank you by the way for you comment.